# Button Submit Inside Serverside Table Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have datatables contain input box and button for each row data, for sure form was added outside table tag, but i have issue while clicking on button submit inside that table, the button did not work well and no appear anything error logs

My **Controller.php** for displaying row:

```
 public function tagihankost()
{
    $list = $this->tagihan->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($list as $tagih) {
        $row = array();
        $format = number_format($tagih->harga, '0', '', '.');
        $row[] = "<input type='text' value='$tagih->bulan' id='bulan' class='rowtagihan'  form='payment-form' readonly>";
        $row[] = "<input type='number' value='$format' id='harga' class='rowtagihan'  form='payment-form' readonly>";
        if ($tagih->status == 200) {
            $row[] = "<span class='badge bg-success' style='color:white'>Lunas</span>";
        } elseif ($tagih->status == 201) {
            $row[] = "<span class='badge bg-warning' style='color:black'>Pending</span>";
        } else {
            $row[] = "<span class='badge bg-danger' style='color:white'>Belum Bayar</span>";
        };
        $row[] = "<button id='pay-button'>Pay!</button>";

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->tagihan->count_all(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->tagihan->count_filtered(),
        "data" => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

My **View.php** :

```
  <div class="card bodycontent">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="tab-pane table-responsive">
                    <table id="tablekost" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Bulan</td>
                                <td>Tagihan</td>
                                <td>Status</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <form id="payment-form" method="post" action="<?= site_url() ?>/snap/finish">
                            <input type="hidden" name="result_type" id="result-type" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="result_data" id="result-data" value="">
                        </form>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the last thing is my **JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pay-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?= site_url() ?>/snap/token',
        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {
            //location = data;

            console.log('token = ' + data);

            var resultType = document.getElementById('result-type');
            var resultData = document.getElementById('result-data');

            function changeResult(type, data) {
                $("#result-type").val(type);
                $("#result-data").val(JSON.stringify(data));
                //resultType.innerHTML = type;
                //resultData.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
            }

            snap.pay(data, {

                onSuccess: function(result) {
                    changeResult('success', result);
                    console.log(result.status_message);
                    console.log(result);
                    $("#payment-form").submit();
                },
                onPending: function(result) {
                    changeResult('pending', result);
                    console.log(result.status_message);
                    $("#payment-form").submit();
                },
                onError: function(result) {
                    changeResult('error', result);
                    console.log(result.status_message);
                    $("#payment-form").submit();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So what i have missed?

Comment: please describe what you mean with "*i have issue while clicking on button...*" and "*the button did not work well...*"

Comment: the button submit come from inside datatable, u can see that in my controller i was add the button inside it, but the form action place it in above tbody (u can see in my views.php) and the button in that table didnt work like didnt have any effect when i click it.

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', '#pay-button', function(e){...});`